# Service worker does not work without refreshing page

Tags: javascript, service-worker

I injected service-worker registration code snippets into JavaScript code. However, it seems that it won't work initially otherwise refresh the page.

register

```
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
  window.addEventListener('load', () => {
    navigator.serviceWorker.register('/sw.js').then(registration => {
      console.log('SW registered: ', registration);
    }).catch(registrationError => {
      console.log('SW registration failed: ', registrationError);
    });
  });
}
```

unregister:

```
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
  window.addEventListener('load', () => {
    navigator.serviceWorker.getRegistrations().then(function (registrations) {
      for (let registration of registrations) {
        registration.unregister()
      }
    })
  });
}
```

Comment: What do you mean "it won't work"? Do you get the "registration failed" log?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2019/09/fresher-sw

Comment: @GuyIncognito Succeed, but SW effect did not work, refresh page needed.

Comment: @Codesigner Seems not related, could you please point out how to configure in detail?

Answer (score 0):

The answer seems that:

- By default, a page's fetches won't go through a service worker unless the page request itself went through a service worker. So you'll need to refresh the page to see the effects of the service worker.
- clients.claim() can override this default, and take control of non-controlled pages

see [detail](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers/lifecycle#:~:text=By%20default,non-controlled%20pages.)